# How do you benefit from creating an NSArray in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Well, I've been learning Objective-C for a while now, and I don't get why creating an NSArray would be beneficial for you. It's just a collection of some stuff right? Why can't you just use them without making an NSArray. Or can you use the objects in it in the implementation of every one of your methods (even if it's a local ivar).

So, any help would be appreciated. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You could make instance variables for every “item” you need:

```
NSString *str1;
NSString *str2;
NSString *str3;
```

…but that’s hard to work with, an array is simply more convenient. What would you do if you wanted to print all these strings?

```
NSLog(@"%@", str1);
NSLog(@"%@", str2);
NSLog(@"%@", str3);
```

Wouldn’t it be easier to loop over an array?

```
NSArray *strings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];
for (NSString *str in strings)
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

How about if you have ten, twenty strings? And what if you don’t know how many strings you will need? What if you want to pass all these items to somebody else? Are you going to pass them one by one?

```
- (void) doSomethingWithString1: (NSString*) str1 andString2: (NSString*) str2…;
```

Or would you rather pass an array?

```
- (void) doSomethingWithMyStrings: (NSArray*) strings;
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys! So, all I have to know now is the methods related to NSArray. And, thanks again!

Comment: I think your answer is the best. THANKS SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

Very often, the `NSArray` you see is a front for an `NSMutableArray` working behind the scenes.

Billing it in the interface as an `NSArray` is just a way to ensure that it cannot be manipulated from without, which could have moderately disastrous consequences. (Thus, when asking for an `NSArray` from an object, you'll usually get a copy of the `NSMutableArray` used internally.)

Understanding why creating an `NSMutableArray` is beneficial is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I think he’s asking precisely why an ordinary mutable array is useful.

Comment: @zoul: I doubt that. The usage scenario for arrays in general is entirely self-evident.

Comment: Maybe not for a 13 year old kid.

Comment: @zoul: It should be to a 13 year old kid that has "been learning Objective-C for a while".

Answer (score 0):

**Different contexts.**

When you use an `NSString` it's generally used for a single value.  It's quite simple.

**NSArray**

If you want to loop through many keys/values, use an `NSArray`.  It is not possible to loop through `NSStrings` because they don't have the order structer that `NSArray`'s do.

**Why use NSString**

It would be silly to call `myArray[0]` and `foo[0]` every time you saved just a value.  NSString is simpler than NSArray, since you can easily set a value on a GUI element (without having to call `myArray[0`])

**Why use NSArray**

It is more flexible than `NSString` because `NSArray` can hold multiple values, which may be needed in certain situations.

**Weighing pros and cons**

Pros (`NSArray`):

Can make your code cleaner (call `myArray[1]` and `myArray[0]` instead of `mystring` and `foo`)

Simplified memory management (easier to release one `NSArray` than many `NSStrings`)

Cons `(NSArray)`:

Can make your code very complicated (was that on `myArray[0`] or 1?)

Might be difficult to know what type of data is in the array (if it's an `NSString`, it's always going to be a string, an array can hold many different types of data).  You wouldn't use 50 tissues to dry yourself off from the shower but use a towel.

So it boils down to one thing.  What context are you using?